# error while executing python script from php

Tags: php, python, mysql

i have published my website using python-php mysql hosting server. Now they told me to create an virtualenv after that i was able to install my required packages like pypi newspaper. My python scripts are totally dependent on pypi newspaper.

Now the issue is that when i call my index.php from publi_html and call my python script it shows me following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):" [1]=> string(79) " File
>   "/home/adpnewsi/public_html/adpScripts/getImage.py", line 3, in "
>   [2]=> string(33) " from newspaper import Article" [3]=> string(38)
>   "ImportError: No module named newspaper" }

Comment: how do you execute your python script ? show more related code;

Comment: This is how I execute my script: $cmd="/usr/bin/python /home/adpnewsi/public_html/adpScripts/getImage.py $murl  2>&1";
$run=exec($cmd,$out) or die("error che");
var_dump($out);

Comment: $murl is the variable holding URL to fetch image

Comment: print your $cmd and try to execute it directly from your terminal;

Comment: and what's the link structure you are trying to grab ?

Comment: I am try to grab content of web portal into my site

Comment: From terminal my scripts runs well but not from webpage

Comment: often this is a permission or ownership issue, due to php runs usually under www-data user;

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the virtual python environment. 
In your terminal type `which python`. 
If the output is `/usr/bin/python` you need to switch to your virtual environment.

Go to the directory where you created your virtualenv and in terminal enter `source bin/activate`. Then use `which python` to verify your are now using your virtual environment to run the server.